# Find Kotlin classes implementing an interface

Tags: android, reflection, kotlin

I am in the process of developing an android application (Parser Application) where we have a parser class which is responsible for actually parsing the work.

I want to provide an extension point to all who want to use the API (beside the some generic parsing which I will provide as part of the API). The idea is to create an interface and if any one wants to declare their class as parser class, all they have to do is, to (declare to) implement the interface.

Then, I want to get the list of all the classes with its instance, implementing that parser.  After that, I want to call the method of the base interface, which will be implemented by the user.

```
Base Interface

interface BaseParser {
    fun parser(key:String):String
}

Implementation

class MyParser: BaseParser {
    override fun parser(key:String):String {
    // actual implementation
}
```

I just want to get the instance of all the class implementing BaseParser (in this case: MyParser) and call the method parser(key) during runtime.

edit: Added Code

Comment: You can't get every instance of a class, but you can get the children

Comment: How do i get the children ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Reflections scans and indexes your project's classpath metadata, allowing reverse transitive query of the type system on runtime.

Using Reflections you can query for example:

Subtypes of a type
Types annotated with an annotation
Methods with annotation, parameters, return type
Resources found in classpath
And more...